# stream soundcloud track with JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, audio, stream, soundcloud

Would you guys help me in this? :
i want to make a list from my soundcloud tracks and play any track when i click it with JavaScript, but it doesn't work with me :(

html file

```
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script> 
<body>
    <ol id="track-list"></ol> 
</body>
```

js file:

```
function PlayIt(ID){
    SC.stream("/tracks"+ID, function(sound){
     soundManager.stopAll();
     sound.play();
    });

}



SC.initialize({
      client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
      redirect_uri: "http://example.com/callback.html",
  });

/**
Once that's done you are all set and ready to call the SoundCloud API. 
**/



/**
Call to the SoundCloud API. 
Retrieves list of tracks, and displays a list with links to the tracks showing 'tracktitle' and 'track duration'
**/

  var userId = 39090345; // user_id of Prutsonic

  SC.get("/tracks", {
      user_id: userId,
      limit: 100
  }, function (tracks) {

      var tmp = '';

      for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
        var TrackId=tracks[i].id;
          tmp = '<a href="#" onclick="PlayIt('+TrackId +')">' + tracks[i].title + ' - ' + tracks[i].duration + '</a>';

          $("<li/>").html(tmp).appendTo("#track-list");
      }

  });
```

You can also check it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/26pHX/96/

*this is not my code, but i try to make it better

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like you need a client id in your code.  You also need a redirect url.  I'm not sure what is expected with that necessarily but I would try feeding it a random page for now because there doesn't seem to be anything special about their example page.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this part was the problem:

> onclick="PlayIt('+TrackId +')

instead i made  tag using document.createElement('a') then i setted its attibutes using (element).setAttribute('the_attribute','the_value');
and everything works well.